# not to run duplicate instances of service

Tags: linux, bash, service, scripting

I am writing a init.d script for kibana

as of not script is running partially, but the issue is if I run run service kibana start even if service is running then second instance start which bothers me I want to add check before starting service, if service is running then dont start second instance. I tried to put if check on "/var/lock/subsys/kibana" but didn't work. Here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

KIBANA_PATH="/opt/kibana4"
DESC="Kibana Daemon"
NAME=kibana
DAEMON=bin/kibana
CONFIG_DIR=$KIBANA_PATH/config/kibana.yml
LOGFILE=/var/log/kibana/kibana.log
#ARGS="agent --config ${CONFIG_DIR} --log ${LOGFILE}"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/kibana
PIDFILE=/var/run/kibana.pid
base=kibana

# Exit if the package is not installed
if [ ! -x "$KIBANA_PATH/$DAEMON" ]; then
{
  echo "Couldn't find $DAEMON"
  exit 99
}
fi

. /etc/init.d/functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#

do_start()
{
       cd $KIBANA_PATH && \
       ($DAEMON >> $LOGFILE &) && \
       success || failure;
}

set_pidfile()
{
  pgrep -f "kibana.jar" > $PIDFILE
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#

do_stop()
{
  pid=`cat $PIDFILE`
                   if checkpid $pid 2>&1; then
                       # TERM first, then KILL if not dead
                       kill -TERM $pid >/dev/null 2>&1
                       usleep 100000
                       if checkpid $pid && sleep 1 &&
                          checkpid $pid && sleep $delay &&
                          checkpid $pid ; then
                            kill -KILL $pid >/dev/null 2>&1
                            usleep 100000
                       fi
                    fi
                    checkpid $pid
                    RC=$?
                    [ "$RC" -eq 0 ] && failure $"$base shutdown" || success $"$base shutdown"

}

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    do_start
    touch /var/lock/subsys/$NAME
    set_pidfile
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
    do_stop
    rm /var/lock/subsys/$NAME
    rm $PIDFILE
    ;;
  restart|reload)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
    do_stop
    do_start
    touch /var/lock/subsys/$NAME
    set_pidfile
    ;;
  status)
    echo $DESC
    status -p $PIDFILE
    echo $!
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

echo
exit 0
```

any help here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use `lockfile -r0 /path/to/lock/file.lck` when you start the service. every new access then will retry zero times to create the file. so if that command fails do nothing or start the service otherwise.

```
lockfile -r0 /path/to/lock/file.lck
if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
  echo "lock does not exist. enter devils land :)"
fi
```

Comment: `if ! lockfile -r0 $lock_file; then echo "oops, already running"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

The following is a pretty standard implementation of this feature used by most `init.d` scripts.

```
start () {
    [ -d /var/run/nscd ] || mkdir /var/run/nscd
    [ -d /var/db/nscd ] || mkdir /var/db/nscd
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon /usr/sbin/nscd $NSCD_OPTIONS
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/nscd
    return $RETVAL
}
...

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
    start)
        [ -e /var/lock/subsys/nscd ] || start
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
...
```